# Combinatorics: pick 2 from group A with 5 elements and 3 that stay in order from group B with 6 elements?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So basically: how many way are there to pick 2 elements from group A which has 5 elements, and pick 3 elements from group B which has 6 elements, provided the 3 elements stay in order in the new 5 element picked set?

Comment: What do you mean by "stay in order in [a] set"?

Comment: They have to stick together in the 5 element picked set.

Comment: Okay. What do you mean by "stay together"? For example, the following sets are **exactly** the same: $$\{1,2,3,4\}$$ $$\{1,2,4,3\}$$ $$\{1,4,2,3\}$$ $$\{4,1,2,3\}$$ In fact, there are $24$ distinct ways to write this set using *roster notation* (by which I mean, simply listing the set's members).

Comment: I guess set is bad terminology. I mean like a line. So like in the line of 5 picked elements, the 3 elements from set B must be consecutive in the line.

Comment: Okay, last question. Does it matter what order the three elements from $B$ are in?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

So we start by choosing $2$ elements from $A$ in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. Then we permute three elements of $B$, which can be done in $\frac{6!}{3!}$. We then cluster these three elements and permute the three clusters of our new set in $3!$ ways. By rule of product, we multiply:

$$\binom{5}{2} \cdot \frac{6!}{3!} \cdot 3!$$

If $B$ is already ordered and we wish to preserve that order, we have to do things differently. So we start by simply choose $3$ elements of $B$, which fixes their order. So we do this in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways. That leaves us with:

$\_b_{1} \_ b_{2} \_ b_{3} \_$

Now we permute the $a_{1}, a_{2}$ elements into the String (filling in the blanks) in $\frac{4!}{2!}$ ways. So by rule of product, we multiply:

$$\binom{6}{3} \cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot \frac{4!}{2!}$$

**Edit**: Based on your comment, I will update my solution.

So we start by permuting the three girls, which can be done in $6!/3!$ ways. We permute because this is a line, so order matters. We now choose our two boys in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. Now we treat the cluster of girls as an object and each boy as an object. We have three objects to permute, so we multiply by $3!$ to get: $6! \cdot \binom{5}{2}$ ways of arranging everyone in a line.

Comment: I'm confused on what you're doing here. I understand why you used C(5, 2), but why did you permute B? Shouldn't we also choose for B, since we just want any 3 elements? And lastly, where did you get the 3! and 4!/2! from?

Comment: In your question, you said: "B which has 6 elements, provided the 3 elements stay in order in the new 5 element picked set?" So it isn't clear to me if the elements of $B$ are in a fixed order or not. If they are not in a fixed order, my first answer covers it. If they are in a fixed order, my second answer covers this. As for the $3!$, we have $a_{1}, (b_{1}b_{2}b_{3}), a_{2}$. We permute these three objects. I explained the $4!/2!$ above. Move the $a_{1}, a_{2}$ elements into the blanks

Comment: Now if you want to choose any three elements of $B$ and have them be in one cluster, but order doesn't matter (so $b_{1}b_{2}b_{3}$ is good, as is $b_{2}b_{1}b_{3}$). Your question in your original post is very ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah, I think I just can't word it the right way. If I can make a 5 person line, let's say, and I can choose 3 girls from a set of 6 girls, and 2 guys from a set of 5 guys, but the 3 girls must stick together, how many different lines can I make?

Comment: Updated with a revision.

Comment: Wouldn't you permute the boys too, since their order makes a difference? For example, A1-B1-B2-B3-A2 is not the same as A2-B1-B2-B3-A1, right?

Comment: That's what the $3!$ term does. I permute the girls in $6!/3!$ ways. Then I showed you the clusters I permute- the two boys and cluster of girls. So I multiply by $3!$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, we are looking at the following situation:

- The set $A$ has $5$ elements.
- The set $B$ has $6$ elements.
- You want to arrange $2$ elements from $A$ and $3$ elements from $B$ in a line, such that the elements of $B$ are adjacent.

Now, the general arrangements you're looking at are of one of the following three forms:

1. $AABBB$
2. $ABBBA$
3. $BBBAA$

Pick any one of the three forms. How many ways are there to arrange $3$ of the $6$ elements of $B$ in the $B$ slots? How many ways are there to arrange $2$ of the elements of $A$ in the $A$ slots? Can you take it from there, given that there are $3$ forms? Feel free to run any answer attempts by me, and I'll check them.

Comment: Is it C(5, 2) * C(6, 3) * 3 ways?

Comment: Very nearly. However, since you've indicated that you're arranging the picked elements (that is, putting them in order), then you won't be using combinations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19244/discussion-on-answer-by-cameron-buie-combinatorics-pick-2-from-group-a-with-5-e).

Comment: @Arthur: That's new (to me). I assume there was a meta discussion about this?